# Django calling a function that returns a value doesn't work

Tags: django, function, return, call

I'm having a problem in calling a function that returns a result, from another function

To make it clear, my functions are:

```
def calculate_questions_vote(request):
    useranswer = Answer.objects.filter (answer_by = request.user)
    positive_votes = VoteUpAnswer.objects.filter(answer = useranswer)
    negative_votes = VoteDownAnswer.objects.filter(answer = useranswer)
    question_vote_rank = sum(positive_votes) - sum(negative_votes.count)
        return question_vote_rank

def calculate_replies(request):
    the_new = News.objects.filter(created_by = request.user)
    reply = Reply.objects.filter(reply_to = the_new)
    reply_rank = sum(reply)
        return reply_rank
```

and I want to call them in another function, so that it could return a value.
I'm calling the function form another function like this:

```
rank = calculate_questions_vote
```

Let's say I just want for now to display the value returned by the function calculate_questions_vote.
Of course, I'm putting the rank variable in the context of the function.

My problem is that my output is:

```
<function calculate_questions_vote at 0x9420144>
```

How can I actually make it display the value returned by the function, instead of that string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is basic Python. What you are doing is simply referring to the function - assigning the function itself to another variable. To actually *call* a function, you need to use parenthesis after its name:

```
calculate_questions_vote()
```

In your case, you've defined that function as needing the `request` object, so you need to use that in the call as well:

```
calculate_questions_vote(request)
```

Comment: this way, my new error is: 'instancemethod' object is not iterable ,though in the template i'm calling it like {{rank}}  - no iteration

Comment: oh, you are actually right, my new problem is eventually the subject of another question. This is how i should have called the function, now i must figure out how i should call the calculate_function_vote (i guess it actually return more than one value, this is the cause of my error - antway, i'm relatively new to python :)  )Thanks so much for answer!

Answer (score 5):

you need to pass a request object to `calculate_questions_vote` like:

```
rank = calculate_questions_vote(request)
```

Comment: now my new error is: 'instancemethod' object is not iterable (though in my tempalte i'm calling it simple {{rank}}) what can it be?